# Setting styles for embedded fonts in jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

i have an issue with generating pdfs in regards to embedding fonts. I just used

```
pdf.addFileToVFS('Acme-Regular-italic.ttf', fontBase64Data);
pdf.addFont('Acme-Regular-italic.ttf', 'Acme', 'italic');
pdf.setFont("Acme", 'italic');
pdf.text("italic Acme", 10, 10);

pdf.addFileToVFS('Acme-Regular.ttf', fontBase64Data);
pdf.addFont('Acme-Regular.ttf', 'Acme', 'normal');
pdf.setFont("Acme", 'normal');
pdf.text("regular Acme", 10, 40);

pdf.addFileToVFS('Acme-Regular-bold.ttf', fontBase64Data);
pdf.addFont('Acme-Regular-bold.ttf', 'Acme', 'bold');
pdf.setFont("Acme", 'bold');
pdf.text("bold Acme", 10, 70);
```

where fontBase64Data is always the Acme.ttf encodes as base64

and the font i see for the three variants is always the same!? So I wonder what I am missing. Do I need to pass different base64 encodingds (one for regular, one for bold...) - whcih I don't have? If so where can I get those?

Here the result i get as screenshot from pdf:
[image]

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 is one input file  one output file so if its built from command

```
base64 -e upright.ttf fontBase64.Data
```

then on decoding that string it can only be one single `upright.ttf`

For each family style you wish to embed you will need separate font ttfs

- normal.ttf
- *italic.ttf*
- **bold.ttf**
- ***bold italic.ttf***

the preferred method is supply the `regular/normal.ttf` `italic/oblique.ttf` and `bold/heavy.ttf` etc. to the converter per the web site method
[image]
https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html

but do read the instructions at https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8

in return you will get the base64 style in a js wrapper [image]

one advantage of holding the data in a referenced fontstyle.js is that the decompressed ttfs do not need to be included inline on the pdf building html page just linked like any other resource.

Comment: Don't really get the first part. Maybe you can rephrase? Regarding the converter this essentially just generates code like
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = base64FontData;
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Pacifico-Regular-italic.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Pacifico-Regular-italic.ttf', 'Pacifico-Regular', 'italic');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])

i.e. from my understanding does the same as I do and I don't need to include all those files for the 50+ fonts I want to use. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sure. That's why in the end Acme will be replaced by fontname in snippet. base64 encoding is not the problem as that works fine - see the pdf screenshot. Problem ist getting that in itatlic, bold etc. Do I understand you right that I need to provide different font files /font base64 strings for normal, bold italic and bolditalic quite unlike in svg or when doing that on the web via webfonts? If so where can I get those if googlefonts only provides me the regular font? Or did I get you wrong?